# setValues() in apps script does not work when fetching data from Trello (could their be a bug in the setValues() method?)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

I have tested my snippet code below. Its purpose is to place the values of an Array into a Google Sheet. It works.

```
   `function testArray() {
var array = [["Re wire light in living room"],
["Refinish kitchen cabinets"],
["Change Sewer access cover"],
["Install cap over pvc in kitchen"],
["Install roof overhang with neighbors roof"],
["Paint side wall"],
["Touch up peeled paint in kitchen 2"],
["ท่อน้ำ"],
["Touch up paint/ repaint kitchen"],
["ต่อท่อน้ำทิ้งเครื่องซักผ้า"],
["new line"]];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
sheet.getRange(2,1,array.length,1).setValues(array);
}`
```

The same code in combination with fetching the array values from Trello does not work. Fetching the values works. Converting those values into an array of arrays works. I have logged both. Placing the prepared array (jobsReformatted) into a sheet does not work. Could anyone tell me what has gone wrong? The problem must be with this line:
**sheet.getRange(2,1,jobsReformatted.length,1).setValues(jobsReformatted);**

```
    function fetchCardsFromTrello_() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 

  // Prompt the user for a list name.
  var listID = Browser.inputBox('Fetch Trello List ID',
      'Please enter the Trello list ID',
      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL); 
   if (listID == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }

  var base = "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/";
  // var listName = "5bf10b78584430134125eb09"
  var queries = "/cards?fields=id,name&";
  var key = "<MY API KEY>";
  var token = "<MY API TOKEN>";
  var url = (base + listID + queries + "key="+key + "&" + "token="+token);
  //var sheetName = "";
  var trello = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = trello.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
  var jobs = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    jobs.push(data[i].name);
  }
  var jobsReformatted = jobs.map(reformatJobs);
  Logger.log(jobsReformatted);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,jobsReformatted.length,1).setValues(jobsReformatted);
}

function reformatJobs(job) {
return "[" + job + "]";
}
```

**I have updated the code but the last step displaying the array in Google Sheets still does not work. Can anyone help?**

```
function fetchCardsFromTrello() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 

  // Prompt the user for a list name.
  var listID = Browser.inputBox('Fetch Trello List ID',
      'Please enter the Trello list ID',
      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL); 
   if (listID == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }

  var base = "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/";
  // var listName = "5bf10b78584430134125eb09"
  var queries = "/cards?fields=id,name&";
  var key = "<MY API KEY>";
  var token = "<MY TOKEN>";
  var url = (base + listID + queries + "key="+key + "&" + "token="+token);
  //var sheetName = "";
  var trello = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = trello.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var jobs = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    jobs.push(data[i].name);
  }
  var convertedJobs = jobs.map(convertTrelloToSheetsArray);
  Logger.log(convertedJobs);
  return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 1).setValues(convertedJobs);
  }

function convertTrelloToSheetsArray(job) {
  return "[" + job + "]";
}
```

Logger.log(convertedJobs); produces this log:

[18-12-22 13:49:03:059 ICT] [[Re wire light in living room], [Refinish kitchen cabinets], [Change Sewer access cover], [Install cap over pvc in kitchen], [Install roof overhang with neighbors roof], [Paint side wall], [Touch up peeled paint in kitchen 2], [ท่อน้ำ], [Touch up paint/ repaint kitchen], [ต่อท่อน้ำทิ้งเครื่องซักผ้า]]

Comment: I am analyzing the files that Trello returns. It seems I am getting more that I have bargained for. Will try to clean them up first and try again.

Comment: The log of my file from trello is now:
[18-12-22 13:49:03:059 ICT] [[Re wire light in living room], [Refinish kitchen cabinets], [Change Sewer access cover], [Install cap over pvc in kitchen], [Install roof overhang with neighbors roof], [Paint side wall], [Touch up peeled paint in kitchen 2], [ท่อน้ำ], [Touch up paint/ repaint kitchen], [ต่อท่อน้ำทิ้งเครื่องซักผ้า]]

I have updated the code above, but I am at a loss why this is not working. Anybody?

Comment: Much to my surprise: setValue() does work and produces only the first line in the array. Logic dictates that setValues(), with s, should produce the entire array. Could this be a bug in the setValues() method?

Comment: From your question and comments, I thought of your situation and posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to put 10 values in your question to "A2:A11".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In your script, each element of `convertedJobs` becomes string.

  - Please put each element to 1 dimensional array.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var jobs = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  jobs.push(data[i].name);
}
var convertedJobs = jobs.map(convertTrelloToSheetsArray);
Logger.log(convertedJobs);
return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 1).setValues(convertedJobs);
```

To:

```
var jobs = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  jobs.push([data[i].name]);
}
return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 1).setValues(jobs);
```

or, you can also use `map()` as follows.

```
var jobs = data.map(function(e){return [e.name]});
return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 10, 1).setValues(jobs);
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If this was not the result you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Superb! I have replaced your suggestion with:
var jobs = data.map(function(e){return [e.name]});
return sheet.getRange(2, 1, jobs.length, 1).setValues(jobs);
It works! I am now trying to understand the difference with my own code. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @JP Douma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you! It's been going thru my mind all night last night. This will help me moving forward. Have a great day!